# Postgres query performance - similar queries different performance

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-performance

Why do recently added records seem to be quicker to retrieve than older records?

I have a postgres table that is being added to at a rate of about 2 million rows per day. It contains an indexed column called ‘fixTime’ of type ‘timestamp’ which records the moment the record was added to the database.

I have noticed that retrieving a set of records (filtered on ‘fixTime’) added in the last 2-3 days seems to take a couple of seconds, but retrieving a similar set of records from 6 months ago can take 3-4 minutes. Why the big difference, and what can I do get similar performance for my older records?

Some background info…..

- Version is “PostgreSQL 9.5.7 on x86_64-pc-mingw64, compiled by
  gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 4.9.2, 64-bit”
- The records are distributed approximately evenly throughout the day (about 20 new records added every second)
- My select queries are identical except
  for the time period specified. Both the fast (recent) and slow (old)
  queries are returning a similar number of records (typically a few
  hundred)
- I accepted all defaults when creating my database – so
  ANALYSE and VACUUM should be on (don’t understand what they do, but I
  gather they’re important!)
- I've tried explain (but don't understand the results) I have noticed that the query plan is different depending on how long ago the data was added.

I had thought that all data was 'equal' and that the speed to return the data should be (mostly) the same irrespective of the when/how it was added. Any ideas on what the issue might be and how to diagnose it?

Comment: maybe it's due to database size ? 
2 millions * 6 * 30 = 360 millions row to iterate.
field fixTime is indexed so database know order but for 3-4 days, it iterate 6-8 millions row (just latest indexed) but for 6 month ago, it need to find where 6 month ago begin and iterate something like 360 millions row before finding rows you need  2s * 6 * 30 => 360s so 6 min without any other optimisation

Comment: Maybe the newer records are still in the disk cache and the older records are not? Is the query on the older dates faster when you run it a second time? (although 3-4 minutes seems like a very long time if you are using an index..)

Comment: @ekans The whole point of an index is so that the database engine can perform a binary search. This would mean you don't iterate the entire table.

Comment: Read and act on the information in the [postgresql-performance info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) link.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), the query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)